# How to click on React Router Link to open tab in new chrome window not in new tab

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I don't want this because  it opens the link in a new tab in the same chrome

```
<Link to="/home" target="_blank">home</Link>
```

I want to click on the link and open it in the new chrome window

I want the code like this but working on Link:

```
window.open(
                  "/console",
                  "window",
                  "width=1600, height=1000",
                  "toolbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes"
                );
```

Comment: let me check brother

Comment: its not working